# Weird session scope issue in PHP

Tags: php, session

I am having a really unsual problem I have never had before, I have a signup page/form and a processing page that for submits to, on the processing page I set any errors that are in the user data like empty fields and set them to a session var array

```
$_SESSION['signup_errors'] = $signup_errors;
```

$signup_errors is an array that I set to the session, I can then access that session data on the same page but I just changed my site around to use mod-rewrite to change the URL's and the only thing that I can seem to think of is on my signup form I cannot access these session variables anymore and now that I use mod-rewrite the url is like this domain.com/account/new and it used to be domian.com/?p=account.new so now it appears that it is in a differnt folder, could that have something to do with it?

I have tried debugging it a lot and that is the only thing I can come up with is maybe because it appears to be a different directory now because of the mod-rewrite maybe that makes the session unaccessible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you're starting sessions on every page you're accessing? I would check to make sure there's

```
session_start();
```

Wherever necessary.

Also, what does

```
print_r( $_SESSION );
```

return? Anything at all? If not it would probably indicate what I was saying.

Comment: Yes sessions is started and here is the kicker, I can access another set os sessions vars on the same page just not that one, im going to jkeep playing with it but this is a weird one

Comment: Is it possible you are unsetting it, or resetting it to a blank array? I would check all instances where you are assigning it.

Comment: I can change the session name and then it all works so somewhere in my crazy complex app it must be killing that particular session name

Comment: yes what you posted, that must be the case somewhere in one of my files

Answer (score 0):

I would check that you're not changing domains. E.G.  domain.com  ->  www.domain.com

Normally a cookie is used to track the session id, and by default, the cookie is tied to a single domain.  I.E.  If the session was created at www.domain.com, when you visited login.domain.com the cookie wouldn't be sent resulting in no session information.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me once, maybe you have a similar scenario. The session variable was temporary and I would destroy it once it was outputted to the screen.

With mod rewrite if you are routing everything, if there is a broken image, that might be redirected to your php script as well, it would in the back ground print out the error and destroy that session var.

Just a thought!